# What is this table and why it there

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I apologize for such vague title, but it partially comes from me being an ESL person.

I am trying to retrieve the information about a SQL Server 2012 database thru the ODBC call `SQLTables()`. It all works fine, but the very first system table name I get is "trace_xe_action_map".

Trying to find what this table I opened Management Studio, but to my surprise I didn't find such table/view.

Does anybody know what this table is and how to handle it?

Moreover, is there any more of such tables that I will get from `SQLTables()` that are not present on the server?

Thank you.

Comment: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929097.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929097.aspx)

Comment: Always google before asking a question

Comment: @Sachu, [quote]This table is stored in the master database, in the sys schema.[/quote]. I don't see this table there, hence my question. I would've guessed that the master db, sys schema should be populated completely when the master db becomes created.

Comment: Maybe SSMS simply hides that table because it's an internal one. Can you run a `select * from trace_xe_action_map` in SSMS?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, here are the results: [quote]Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'trace_xe_action_map'.[/quote]

Comment: Try this `SELECT * FROM sys.trace_xe_action_map` it perfectly works.

Comment: @gofr1, weird, the query works, but the table definition is still not present. But at least now I know how to modify my program. Thank you. P.S. Sorry there was no answer to give you more credit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well documented table. You can find the complete documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929097.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: @ShikharMaheshwani, It may be well documented, but I don't see it in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. I was expecting for the master DB to make all the tables that should be there when the master DB is created.

Comment: @Igor, do you have SQL Server 2012? Because, if you don't have it, then SQL Server 2012 Management Studio is just a visual tool to access the database and its objects. If your database is SQL Server 2008, then you will not be able to see the table in the Master database. But, then I am surprised how your ODBC call is showing that table.

Comment: @ShikharMaheshwani, of course I do. Otherwise I won't be able to connect and call SQLTables(). And my DB is definitely SQL Server 2012.